# How to use a bash script as a user's shell in centOS 7?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, login

I have user `test` and I want to provide a bash script as a login shell for this user. I was able to do it on centOS 6 easily by using the command `usermod -s /pathtomyscript.sh`. But in centOS 7 I am unable to do it like this. I copied the script to `/usr/bin` and added it to `/etc/shells`. But still no luck. My script is the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
export PATH

whiptail --title "Example Dialog" --msgbox "You are logged in and now click ok to exit!" 8 78
```

I am able to login by running `su`, but when I login into console, it is saying that `no shell, permission denied`. I have already given the proper permission to the file like the following:

```
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 test test 240 Jan 19 15:57 /usr/bin/testshell.sh
```

Comment: Maybe research SELinux, in particular `grep | audit2allow`

Comment: What is the exact error message  displayed or in your logs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need, to some script or program acts as user's login shell - you must append it's full path to `/etc/shells` file.

[pam_shells](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_shells) module checks for user login shell in this file.